# Fail to set web element state "selected' using js and Selenium

Tags: javascript, jquery, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have two lines of code that one is unhidding the web element since its hidden, and the other suppose to select it.

```
js.executeScript("$('.select-upload_company_id>.center').html('Test')") 
js.executeScript("$('#company_id option:contains(\"Test\")').eq(1).attr('selected','selected')")
```

from some reason the first line change the dropdown text to "Test" which is the requested choice, but the second line is not changing it to "selected"...seams like the change is only visually.

someone knows what might be the issue?
tnx

Answer (score 0):

jQuery's `.eq()` method is zero-based. Assuming your "Test" is the only one, you'll want to use `.eq(0)` to select that element.

Comment: its not solving it :/

Comment: Try writing the :contains selector without the quotes around Test like
   `:contains(Test)`